# How to make TextInput a separated component in this case

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I have a working ASK Component, it basically takes user input and push to Firebase database.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Linking,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import Input from '../components/Input';
import {firebaseApp} from '../Firebase';

export default class Ask extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.itemsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();
    this.state = {

      text:''
    };
  }
  additem(){

    this.itemsRef.push({ title: this.state.text })
    this.setState({text:''})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Insert Item Here!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
          onSubmitEditing= {this.additem.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.text}
        >
        </TextInput>
        {/* Many other components here */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to move TextInput component to a separated file (create an INPUT component). (make INPUT component a presentational component, and ASK component a container component)

However, in Ask Component, I do not know how to retrieve the `text` state value of Input Component so that I can call `this.itemsRef.push({ title: THE_TEXT_STATE_VALUE_OF_INPUT_COMPONENT  })`

Here is my code.

Input.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput,PropTypes} from 'react-native'


export default class Input extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text:''}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput style={styles.textinput}
        placeholder = {this.props.placeholder}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        onSubmitEditing= {this.props.AddItem}
      >
      </TextInput>
    )
  }
}
```

Ask.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Linking,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import Input from '../components/Input';
import {firebaseApp} from '../Firebase';

export default class Ask extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.itemsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();
    this.state = {

      text:''
    };
  }
  additem(){

    this.itemsRef.push({ title: this.state.text })
    this.setState({text:''})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Inser here" AddItem={this.additem.bind(this)}> ////// THIS IS WRONG
        </Input>
        {/* Many other components here */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Ask.js like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Linking,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ListView,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

import Input from '../components/Input';
import {firebaseApp} from '../Firebase';

export default class Ask extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.itemsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();
    this.state = {
      text:''
    };

    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
    this.additem = this.additem.bind(this);
  }
  additem(){
    this.itemsRef.push({ title: this.state.text })
    this.setState({text:''})
  }

  inputChange(entered_text){
    this.setState({text: entered_text })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Inser here" AddItem={ this.additem } inputChange={ this.inputChange }> ////// THIS IS WRONG
        </Input>
        {/* Many other components here */}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and

Input.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput,PropTypes} from 'react-native'


export default class Input extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text:''}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput style={styles.textinput}
        placeholder = {this.props.placeholder}
        onChangeText={ this.props.inputChange }
        onSubmitEditing= {this.props.AddItem}
      >
      </TextInput>
    )
  }
}
```

now input component will update state of Ask component.

Comment: hi, thanks. it works!but i am very confused. I thought only Ask component can control and send data to Input component. In your code, it seems the Input component send data/text to Ask component. It is quite strange to me.

Comment: We can do both ways. as per my answer, we are catching submit and change event in ask component and another way we can send input state as parameter to ask component function.